# GetPreviewToken Does Not Return a Response

Tags: experience-manager

In an XPM implementation, when saving or "updating preview" a call is made to `http://CMSERVERURL/WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetPreviewToken`.

This call is not returning any response (of any kind, success, fail, not found) and I've not found anything interesting (Errors or Warnings) in the Preview OData web-service logs (on Debug mode)

The web-service seems to be working correctly, as requesting `/session/ws/odata.svc/Components` returns results

Comment: Have you installed and configured preview service which is required in addition to session service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a proxy / load balancer issue.

We now get tokens, but with very varied performance (10 seconds to 2 minutes), which appears to be based on the Component/Component Template combination and how broadly it is used/linked elsewhere

e.g.

- Component on one page - seconds
- Component heavily linked/used on other pages - minutes